# Previous user name still appears in login screen in after renamed/removed?

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, username

When using `lusrmgr.msc` to renamed/removed a user account, I still see it in login screen.

I want the new name appear there only. What can I do to work around that?

Comment: Have you tried a restart?

Comment: Yes of course I tried - the machine gets restarted every day.